# função no R que também retorna o próprio tempo de execução

Tags: r, funções, runtime

Eu sei que existe o Rprof(), mas ele me parece bastante impreciso comparado ao microbenchmark(). Contudo, se quero usar o microbenchmark() eu tenho que chamar a função 2 vezes, uma para ter a saída dela e outra para executar o tempo dela (o que me parece bastante inviável)

Não sei como fazer para chamar a função apenas 1 vez e ter como resposta a saída normal dela e também o tempo de execução bastante preciso.

A função não é essa, mas segue um exemplo do meu problema:

```
teste <- function(x){

  Rprof()
  x <- x+2
  Rprof(NULL)

  return(summaryRprof())
}
guarda_x_e_tempo <- teste(2)
```

ou

```
teste <- function(x){
  x <- x+2
  return(x)
}
guarda_x <- teste(2)
guarda_tempo <- teste(2)
```

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida?

Comment: nao sei como fazer para chamar a função apenas 1 vez e ter como resposta a saída normal dela e também o tempo de execução bastante preciso

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione esta informação. Sem ela, sua pergunta está incompleta e poderá ser sinalizada e fechada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se o seguinte é o que quer.
O resultado da função R base `proc.time` é obtido logo na primeira instrução da função `teste` e depois subtraído de `proc.time` no fim.

```
teste <- function(x){
  ini <- proc.time()
  x <- x + 2
  list(result = x, tempo = proc.time() - ini)
}

guarda_x_e_tempo <- teste(2)

guarda_x_e_tempo
#$`result`
#[1] 4
#
#$tempo
#   user  system elapsed 
#      0       0       0
```

Agora outra função, mais demorada.

```
teste2 <- function(x, n = 1e6){
  ini <- proc.time()
  for(i in seq_len(n)) x <- x + 2
  list(result = x, tempo = proc.time() - ini)
}

teste2(2)
#$`result`
#[1] 2000002
#
#$tempo
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.08    0.00    0.08 
#
```

Outra maneira é por a expressão a cronometrar em `system.time`. Isto permite cronometrar a execução sem modificar as funções.

```
teste3 <- function(x, n = 1e6){
  for(i in seq_len(n)) x <- x + 2
  x
}

system.time(teste3(2))
# usuário   sistema decorrido 
#   0.048     0.000     0.049
```

Answer (score 2):

Adenilson, tudo bem?

Acredito que a função system.time atende a sua necessidade:

```
funcao_exemplo <- function(x) {
  print(x)
}

system.time(funcao_exemplo("Hello World"))
```

Comment: Benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português. É sempre bom ver novos usuários, em especial quando têm coisas a dizer mas, neste caso concreto, eu já tinha respondido isto. Por favor continua a contribuir, mas antes lê as outras respostas.

Comment: Olá Rui, tudo bem? Ao contrário do que você declarou, eu li sim as outras repostas, no entanto, tive o intuito de atender àqueles que buscam uma resposta clara e simples, por isso redigi uma resposta de 3 linhas. Agradeço a preocupação, mas pode ficar tranquilo, pois li e sigo o regulamento do fórum.

Answer (score 2):

A precisão do `microbenchmark` está em rodar várias vezes as funções evitando assim ser influenciada por possíveis travadas do computador que poderiam afetar o tempo de execução. Quando você roda o `microbenchmark` ele roda por padrão 100x a função para poder calcular média, mediana , eco dos tempos de execução.

Dito isso, `microbenchmark` não é adequado para o que você quer fazer.

Acredito que as outras respostas já tenham boas soluções, mas acho que uma forma elegante de fazer isso, seria criar uma função da seguinte forma:

```
crono <- function(f) {
  function(...) {
    exec_time <- system.time({res <- f(...)})
    list(
      exec_time = exec_time,
      res = res
    )
  }
}
```

Chamamos esse tipo de função de [**Function Operators**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Function-operators.html).

Com ela você pode criar versões de suas funções que sejam cronometradas, por exemplo:

```
crono_mean <- crono(mean)
crono_mean(1:10000000)
```

Que resultaria em:

```
$exec_time
   user  system elapsed 
  0.034   0.018   0.061 

$res
[1] 5e+06
```